# How to check user and password ? 

Tags: c#, sql-server, security

What is the best practice to check user by login and password? I know two ways, but could not choose most security and right way.

1. Check in sql like `where login = @login and password = @password` with using stored procedure
2. Firstly select user by login and after do password check in code. (C#)

Also what is official standard to check password strength?

Comment: One thing you haven't mentioned is whether or not you are hashing the password values. You'll want to do that.

Comment: Option #1 would require **plain text passwords** to be stored - **NOT** a good option!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for first way only 
check the user and password in database side procedure only.

Modification to this first encrypt and store encrypted the password store it in database when creating user.

than when checking for user login, comapre this encrypted password only , by seding encrypted password as parameter to the proceudre ...

For password stength 
Try using googles Google Password Strength API http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/GooglePasswordStrength.aspx

Comment: A one-way hashing algorithm is a safer choice than reversible encryption.  There should not be a reason that you need to recover a password in plaintext.

Comment: @user92546 - yeah that is the thin i told in my answer stored encrypted password only , which is one way encryption....I hope you got my point in answer

Comment: You have a terminology problem: encryption is never one-way, but hashing usually is.